# Why I need to click twice on the submit button to submit my form?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, submit, mixpanel

I have a form which is validated with jquery and once it's submitted I want to call a function (track_forms function to track it with Mixpanel).

It's working alright except one thing: I have to click twice to the button to submit the form. The first click doesn't do anything. I guess there's a problem using submitHandler since the issue came after implementing that.

Does anybody has an idea what's the issue?

Thanks

```
  $.validator.addMethod(
    'ContainsAtLeastOneNumber',
    function (value) { 
        return /[0-9]/.test(value); 
    },  
    'Please enter at least 8 characters containing numbers and letters.'
);

$.validator.addMethod(
    'ContainsAtLeastOneLetter',
    function (value) { 
        return /[a-z]/.test(value); 
    },  
    'Please enter at least 8 characters containing numbers and letters.'
);


$('#signupForm').validate({    
rules: {
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    password: {
        minlength: 8,
        ContainsAtLeastOneNumber: true,
        ContainsAtLeastOneLetter: true,
        required: true
    },
    confirmPassword: {
        required: true,
        equalTo: "#password"
    },
    terms: {
        required: true,
    }
},
messages: {
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    password: {
      required: "Please enter at least 8 characters containing numbers and letters.",
      minlength: "Please enter at least 8 characters containing numbers and letters.",
    },
    confirmPassword: {
      required: "Please enter at least 8 characters containing numbers and letters.",
      equalTo: "The passwords are not matching.",
    },
    terms: {
        required: "You must agree with our Terms of Service.",
    },
},
highlight: function(element) {
    var id_attr = "#" + $( element ).attr("id") + "1";
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');         
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    var id_attr = "#" + $( element ).attr("id") + "1";
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');         
},
errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr('name') == 'terms' ) {
        error.insertAfter(".some-class");
        } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
submitHandler: function(form) {
 mixpanel.track_forms("#signupForm", "Created Account");
    } 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling `track_forms` inside `submitHandler`.

`submitHandler` is called when the form is submitted, but calling `track_forms` doesn't track that the form has been submitted.

`track_forms` sets up a new handler on the `submit` event of the form. Then, when you click the submit button it triggers a Mixpanel event and then continue with the form submission.

---

Right now this is what's happening:

1. The form is submitted and validated, then `submitHandler` is called
2. `submitHandler` sets up the Mixpanel form tracking
3. ??? [form submission is prevented]
4. You click the button again and Mixpanel tracks it

I don't fully understand what happens in step 3 though, where the first form isn't being submitted.

You can try calling track_forms before the submit button is clicked. However, using Mixpanel's `track_forms` might interfere with your validation functionality. If it does it's best to just track a normal event inside the `submitHandler` and then wait before continuing the submission, to ensure that the event has been tracked.

Comment: I've tried calling track_form when the form has been validated but not submitted yet...it messes up the validation and tracking is buggy as well. What do you mean by track a normal event and then wait? Could you provide me a code, i'm fairly new to jquery. Thanks

Comment: @coce I mean calling `mixpanel.track` and passing in a callback, like this: `mixpanel.track("Created Account", function () {  continueFormSubmission(); })`. The callback will be triggered when Mixpanel has confirmed that the event has been received, so it's safe to navigate away from the current page.

Comment: @coce Calling `mixpanel.track_forms` by itself won't track events. What it does is listen to the "submit" event on the DOM and then track an event when the form is submitted. When you use `track_forms` you have to set up the tracking before the form is submitted, otherwise use `mixpanel.track` directly.

Comment: Sorry Matt, I don't really get you...the code i'm using now with `mixpanel.track_forms` tracks the event. I can see the action in mixpanel. The only problem is I have to hit the button twice...as I said I'm a beginner with jquery so I'm not sure where and how to implement to code you've written. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Ok, I figured it out...thanks Matt for the help. This works: `submitHandler: function(form) {
 mixpanel.track("Created Account");
    form.submit();
  }` Thanks!